# How to call a function that has self as a parameter?

Tags: python, nltk

I've found some code online that may help me with a project that I'm doing, the problem is that it uses 2 parameters, one of which is self. I don't know how to all a function like that and would be really grateful if someone could explain how.

Here's the code

```
#code found online
def common_contexts(self, words, num=20):
    """
    Find contexts where the specified words appear; list
    most frequent common contexts first.

    :param word: The word used to seed the similarity search
    :type word: str
    :param num: The number of words to generate (default=20)
    :type num: int
    :seealso: ContextIndex.common_contexts()
    """
    if '_word_context_index' not in self.__dict__:
        #print('Building word-context index...')
        self._word_context_index = ContextIndex(self.tokens,
                                                key=lambda s:s.lower())

    try:
        fd = self._word_context_index.common_contexts(words, True)
        if not fd:
            print("No common contexts were found")
        else:
            ranked_contexts = [w for w, _ in fd.most_common(num)]
            print(tokenwrap(w1+"_"+w2 for w1,w2 in ranked_contexts))

    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
#How I tried to call it, lines[1] is an array containing words
df=common_contexts(lines[1])
print(df)
```

I just want to see the output so that I can tell whether or not I can use this code in my project

Comment: Generally, that's not a function but a *method*. It'll be on a class, and you'd call it on an instance of the class. In that case Python provides `self` for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a *method*. You are looking at the [source code for `nltk.text`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html), and this is `ContextIndex.common_contexts()`.

You need to create an instace of the `ContextIndex` class, then call the method on that:

```
ci = ContextIndex(tokens)
df = ci.common_contexts(lines[1])
```

Here `common_contexts` is then *bound* to the `ci` instance. Calling the method then causes *Python* to provide a value for the `self` parameter; the instance on which the method was called.

Comment: Thanks man, I feel a bit simple for not noticing I was looking at nltk source code.